# R: How to list all levels of a factor variable by summarise function

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

Neighorhood is a factor variable with more than 20 levels and I want to see the standard deviation of all levels but I can only see 10 rows by the summarise function. How can I deal with the problem?

```
train  %>%
group_by(Neighborhood)  %>%
summarise(sd(price))
## # A tibble: 27 x 2
##    Neighborhood `sd(price)`
##          <fctr>       <dbl>
##  1      Blmngtn    26454.86
##  2      Blueste    10381.23
##  3       BrDale    13337.59
##  4      BrkSide    37309.91
##  5      ClearCr    48068.69
##  6      CollgCr    52786.08
##  7      Crawfor    71267.56
##  8      Edwards    54851.63
##  9      Gilbert    41190.38
## 10       Greens    29063.42
## # ... with 17 more rows
```

Comment: Add the code used and a sample of the data.

Comment: The question is not clear.  Please show a small reproducible example and expected output based on that example

Comment: It depends on how you would like to 'view' the data. Try adding `%>% View()` to see it. But I'm echoing @Terru_theTerror and @Akrun's comments.

Comment: I think you need to view the full data.  By default the `print` method for `tibble` shows a fixed number of rows (you may change that in options) otherwise use `%>% as.data.frame`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does :

```
tr %>% 
    group_by(Neigh) %>% 
    summarise(sd(pri)) %>%
    print(n=40)
```

solve the problem?